# Outlook client free/busy not showing

Tags: outlook, exchange-server-2010

I've got an odd problem.

I got my PC reimaged, and now it won't connect properly to the autodiscover service. 
 I cannot see free/busy information, cannot set my out of office, and don't get tooltips about other people who have out of office on when I am emailing them.

If I run the "Test email autoconfiguration" tool, it fails.

All of that used to work before my PC was reimaged. 
 Furthermore, if I log in to another PC (same OS, Win7) it does all work.

So I think the problem is specific to my PC, and not a problem with our Exchange setup.

If I browse to the url http://mail.mydomain/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml I get a 403 error. 
 Doing the above on the other PC works.

Weirdly, if I browse to https://mail.mydomain/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml on the PC with the problem it works OK.

So there's something configured wrong on my PC, but I don't know what. Maybe it's not passing my credentials properly. 
 Other sites that rely on my Windows credentials are working OK, so it's passing them correctly sometimes. 
 Any ideas, before I get them to reimage my PC again?

Thanks

When I run Test mail autoconfiguration, on the Results tab I get:

```
Autoconfiguration has started, this may take up to a minute
Autoconfiguration was unable to determine your settings!
```

The log is:

```
SMTP=my.email@my.domain
Attempting URL httpx://mail.my.domain/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml found through SCP
Autodiscover to httpx://mail.my.domain/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml starting
GetLastError=0; httpStatus=403
Autodiscover request completed with http status code 403
Autodiscover to httpx://mail.my.domain/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml failed (0x80004005)
Autodiscover to httpsx://mail.my.domain/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml starting 
GetLastError=12007; httpStatus=0
Autodiscover to httpsx://mail.my.domain/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml failed (0x800C8203)
Autodiscover to httpsx://autodiscover.my.domain/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml starting 
GetLastError=12007; httpStatus=0
Autodiscover to httpsx://autodiscover.my.domain/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml failed (0x800C8203)
Local autodiscover for my.domain starting
Local autodiscover for my.domain failed (0x8004010F)
Redirect check to httpx://autodiscover.my.domain/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml starting    Redirect check to httpx://autodiscover.my.domain/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml starting
Srv Record lookup for httpx://my.domain starting
Srv Record lookup for my.domain Failed (0x8004010F)
```

Note I had to change http to httpx and https to httpsx to allow it to post.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, this is not a programming question. Secondly, try to run a test from https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/

Comment: Dmitry, thanks for that link.
I don't think it's going to help solve the problem, as that's just testing external access to the Exchange server. As above, it's not the server that's the problem, because it works fine on another PC in the office.

Comment: When you run "Test email autoconfiguration" from the Outlook tray popup, what is the exact error? Can you post the log?

Comment: Thanks Dmitri.Log posted in OP.